# Genesis 5:2, grammatically, how does a plural pronoun refer to a singular noun?

Tags: hebrew, genesis, grammar

Genesis 5:2 (DRB):

> He created them male and female; and blessed them: and called **their** name **Adam,** in the day when they were created.

How does the plural pronoun refer to singular noun (called **their** name **Adam** )? What does this mean?

Comment: Each individually is called *(hu)man*, which is what *adam* means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a subtlety in the use of the Hebrew word, אָדָם (Adam) which can mean either "mankind" generally or the first man, Adam.  The first two verses of Gen 5 read (NASB)

> *This is the book of the generations of Adam (אָדָ֑ם). In the day that God created man (אָדָ֔ם), He made him in His own likeness. Male and
>   female He created them, and He blessed them. And in the day they were
>   created, He called them "man (אָדָ֔ם)"* [or "mankind"].

Note the slight differences in the pointing of אָדָם vs אָדָ֔ם ; both are noun masculine singular, but the first is a proper name (for Adam) while the second means "mankind" generally.

Thus, Gen 5:2 is correct that the two people were both members of the race of creatures known as mankind (singular).

Answer (score 5):

In Gen. 2:19, it is written, “...whatever Adam called the living creature, **this was its name**.” Did Adam name each individual creature? No, rather, he named each “kind” or species of living creature, whether it be the “cow,” “goat,” “eagle,” etc.

Likewise, in Gen. 5:2, when it is written that God “called their name אָדָם,” it is not referring to a personal name, but rather, the name that identifies the “kind” (מִין) or species that God had just created. The name of that species was אָדָם, or “human.”

Regarding Gen. 1:26–27 and Gen. 5:2, Shedd writes,<sup>1</sup>

> In Gen. 1:26, 27, the man and the woman together are denominated “man.” In these two verses, as in the remainder of the first chapter, the Hebrew אָדָם is not a proper name. It does not denote the masculine individual Adam alone, but the two individuals, Adam and Eve, together. **Adam**, here, **is the name of the** human pair, or **species**. It is not until the second chapter of Genesis, that the word is used as a proper name... **Compare Gen. 5:2, where the same usage occurs**.

```
Footnotes
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> Shedd, p. [19](https://books.google.com/books?id=fuFJAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA19#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sup>

Of course, the first male of the human species was also named אָדָם (Adam), but this is not the type of naming that occurs in Gen. 5:2.

---

#### Reference

Shedd, William Greenough Thayer. [*Dogmatic Theology.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=fuFJAAAAMAAJ) Vol. 2. New York: Charles Scribner’s Sons, 1888.